# Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines. (without using fontenc or inputenc)

Tags: xetex, overleaf

I'm compiling my document with `XeLaTex` on Overleaf. Here is the minimal code:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Language setting
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% Set page size and margins
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

% Chinese packages
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono CJK TC}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans CJK TC}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{bsmi}

\section{Testing}

我是一個大笨蛋

\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

The following warning appears:

> Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.

But I didn't use `inputenc` package at all.

How can I avoid this warning? Thanks.

Comment: by not using \usepackage{CJKutf8} which is not meant for unicode engines.

Comment: Thanks, the warning is a bit misleading.

Comment: the warning is from the inputenc package and is quite correct. The cjkutf8 package doesn't test for the engine, it is too old for this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer looks like an answer to me